# System.Text.Json in Azure Function v3: JsonResult.SerializerSettings must be an instance of type JsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, azure-functions, system.text.json

I have a set of Azure Functions v3 running on .NET Core 3.1.

I need to specify custom `System.Text.Json` converters so I provided a custom `JsonSerializerOptions` instance when I build a `JsonResult` in my function:

```
return new JsonResult(<ContractClass>, NSJsonSerializerOptions.Default)
{
    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK
};
```

**Question**

I get the following error and I am not sure where Newtonsoft is coming from since ASP.NET Core is supposed to use `System.Text.Json`:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson: Property 'JsonResult.SerializerSettings' must be an instance of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'.
```

**Update**

I found out that the `JsonResult` instance is looking for an implementation of `IActionResultExecutor<JsonResult>` and gets an `NewtonsoftJsonresultExecutor` instead of an `SystemTextJsonResultExecutor`. Here is the code for the `JsonResult`'s `ExecuteResultAsync` method:

[image: JsonResult]

I would have though that the Azure Function would rely on ASP.Net Core which relies on `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5376

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, I just created a new class which inherits from `ContentResult`.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorApp.Api.Models
{
    public class SystemTextJsonResult : ContentResult
    {
        private const string ContentTypeApplicationJson = "application/json";

        public SystemTextJsonResult(object value, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
        {
            ContentType = ContentTypeApplicationJson;
            Content = options == null ? JsonSerializer.Serialize(value) : JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, options);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is used like:

```cs
[FunctionName("IntakeCount")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIntakeCountAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
{
    var result = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<...>(...);

    return new SystemTextJsonResult(result);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer and worked great for me to remove legacy Json dependency and convert to Sytem.Text.Json consistently.

Answer (score -2):

Your serialized item must be inherit from `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
 new { Testc = "test" },
 new JsonSerializerOptions()
 {
     PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
     //ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
     //ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
}
```

Comment: You say it must inherit from `JsonSerializerSettings` (which is part of Newtonsoft), but you use `JsonSerializerOptions` (which is part of `System.Text.Json`). Since we're talking about the latter, I assume you mean `JsonSerializerOptions`, but I didn't want to change it without confirming your intent. Can you review your answer and edit accordingly?